# Questions about Wilk's phenomenon(or $\chi^2$ distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ having mean $\mu$ and finite covariance matrix $V_0$ of rank $q>0$. Let
>   $$S=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)(X_i-\mu)^\prime,$$
>   then we have
>   $$n(\bar{X}-\mu)^\prime S^{-1}(\bar{X}-\mu)\overset{d}\to\chi^2_q.$$

First question: Is this statement true? What's the name of this theorem, and where can I find this theorem or how can I prove it?

> Note that we can express $EX_i=\mu$ as $E(X_i-\mu)=0$.Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose $E[m(X_i,\mu)]=0$, where $m(X_i,\mu)\in\mathbb{R}^s$ and $Var(m(X_i,\mu))$ is finite with rank $q>0$. Let 
>   $$M=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nm(X_i,\mu)$$
>   and 
>   $$Q=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nm(X_i,\mu)m^\prime(X_i,\mu)$$
>   Can we conclude that
>   $$nM^\prime Q^{-1}M\overset{d}\to\chi^2_q?$$

Second question: Is this generalized form of the first statement true? What's the name of this theorem, and where can I find this theorem or how can I prove it? Do we need further assumptions to function $m(X_i,\mu)$?

Comment: Aren't these direct consequences of the CLT, LLN, and the portmanteau theorem?  And isn't your second question just a repackaging of the first?

Comment: I think the first result follows from [Cochran's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem#Distributions). 

Specifically, looking at the section on distributions, you can see that scaling the sample mean shifted data squared by the variance gives you a $\chi^2$ distribution. I think after some algebra and applying the LLN to $S$ everything falls into place.

Also I think kimchi lover is right, and that if you just denote $m(X,\mu)$ as a new random variable, then, because it's mean 0, $M$ and $Q$ are just the sample mean and sample covariance.

Comment: Actually, I think there is an additional requirement that the random variable $m(X,\mu)$ also be normally distributed.

Comment: @RyanWarnick Thank you for your kind comment!

Comment: @kimchilover  Thank you for your kind comment!